# List all degree 42 polynomials that pass through the eleven points with a constant of 42

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I am having trouble figuring out (1) how to conceptualize this problem and (2) how to approach it.

The question is regarding interpolation: List all degree 42 polynomials that pass through the eleven points $(-5,5),(-4,4),...,(4,-4),(5,-5)$ AND have a constant of 42.

I'm guessing that the approach to this problem may involve generalizing the Lagrange interpolation method, but I am not sure how to do this nor account for the constant of 42.

How can I list all of the degree 42 polynomials listed here that have a constant of 42?

Comment: So your polynomial must pass through the point (0,0) and have a constant term of 42?

Comment: Yes, (0,0) is one of these points

Comment: And by a constant of 42 you mean that the coefficient of the x^0 term is 42?

Comment: There is none. Such a polynomial $f(x)$ would satisfy $42=f(0)=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: @Crostul Yes, but it's better if he gets there himself.

Comment: I don't think the question is referring to the x_0 term. Check out this solution: http://imgur.com/a/dsoQp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unconventional notation for the desired polynomial, $t$ for the variable, and $x_i$ for the coefficient of $t^i$, that is:
$$f(t) =x_0 + x_1t+x_2t^2+\cdots x_{42}t^{42}\qquad(*)$$.

You want this polynomial to pass through some 11 points, say $(a_1,b_1),\ldots(a_{11},b_{11})$. This means $f(a_i)=b_i$. Substituting  $t=a_i$ in $(*)$ we get 11 linear equations in the 42 variables $x_i$.

IN general this will have infinitely many solutions (when consistent). ANy solutions for the $x_i$'s give rise to one such polynomial you desire.